# Why does WP JSON API use nonce

Tags: json, wordpress, api

A collegue recently asked what is the point of the nonce on WP JSON API

https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/

Since you can generate one without authentication, why bother with the extra step of having them at all?

I didn't know, and assumed maybe the authentication could be tightened later, but thought I would ask here in case someone knew.

Thanks in advance